# How to make voice/video call in pidgin (XMPP)?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, pidgin

I'm using `ejabberd` as my XMPP server and `Pidgin` as my client.

My `ejabberd` version is **22.05** and my `Pidgin` version is **2.14.10**

I have configured my ejabberd server for making voice/video call by following [this](https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-set-up-ejabberd-video-voice-calling/) article.

Now what should I do to make **voice/video** call through `pidgin`? I didn't see any plugins for enabling voice/video chat in pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

As at today (7/11/2022), the pidgin website says that the voice and video calls support is still under development. Check this link: https://pidgin.im/development/voice-and-video/

I only know Gajim Client and Conversations Client does support voice and video calls.

Comment: Is an issue tracking this anywhere?